# Including Facebook Javascript SDK in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to load FB's javascript SDK asynchronously. Followed these instructions:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

But 'FB' is undefined when the following code executes in /assets/js/some-file:

```
$(window).load ->
  setFbSize()

setFbSize = ->
  FB.Canvas.setSize # This triggers the error
    ...
```

Synchronous loading works fine. I can get it to work when I load the following in application.html.haml:

`%script{:src => "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"}`

...and then include this in my index.html.haml:

```
:javascript

    FB.init({
        appId:'#{CONFIG['app_id']}', cookie:true,
        status:true, xfbml:true
    });
```

How can I get the asynchronous loading to work? I think it may actually be loading (because when I combine synch/asynch solutions it tells me FB.init has been executed twice), but loading after the code in /assets/js/some-file.coffee gets executed. How can I verify that FB has been loaded before running that code (if that is the problem?)

Answer (score 0):

There are possibilities that FB SDK has not been completely loaded when load event of window is issued.
Any code which would access FB object should be executed in the function registered to window.fbAsyncInit.
The [document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) says:

> The function assigned to window.fbAsyncInit is run as soon as the SDK
>   is loaded. Any code that you want to run after the SDK is loaded
>   should be placed within this function and after the call to FB.init.